# how to combine 2 sql queries to get 1 result

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

```
SELECT users.name, users.registrationdate, users.city, users.status
FROM users, referrals
WHERE users.username= referrals.referrals AND referrals.username='user_name'

SELECT adearning, reffearning
FROM earnings WHERE usersname='user_name33'
```

How can I combine these two queries as if first query condition doesn't match and doesn't run.. then the second query should run and return some value if condition match

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It would help make the question clearer

Comment: These are different queries on different tables and column count/types.  This is something which you should probably handle in your app layer.

Comment: You should have the same return columns (in number and type) to use `UNION`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: ***NOTE****  If both queries run succussfully then result must be returned as a single result(array)

Comment: you can run both separate and merge it to one array.

Comment: i think from queries ... its clear what i want... btw what should i tell about it more

Comment: #abdulla Nilam you mean expanding two arrays and then merging it to one??? i think that a bad practise

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanAyazKhan i dont thinks so. do it separate and merge. Impossible with query level

Comment: @AbdullaNilam :( hmm

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanAyazKhan check below example what i explained

Comment: where is example? @AbdullaNilam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT users.name, users.registrationdate, users.city, users.status 
                            FROM users, referrals 
                            WHERE users.username = referrals.referrals AND referrals.username='user_name'")
$result1 = $query1->result_array();


$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT adearning, reffearning FROM earnings WHERE usersname='user_name33' ")
$result2 = $query2->result_array();


$dataArray = array_merge($result1, $result2);
```

if want to check the result, end of the line add this

```
print_r($dataArray);die;
```

> On this it will print all of them in one array

---

**Example**

```
$result1 = array(
    '0' => 'sjhccsd', 
    '1' => 'ddd', 
    '2' => 'df', 
    '3' => 'dfd', 
    );

$result2 = array(
    '0' => 'sjhccsd', 
    '1' => 'ddd', 
    '2' => 'df', 
    '3' => 'dfd', 
    );


$dataArray = array_merge($result1, $result2);

print_r($dataArray);
```

**Output** : `Array ( [0] => sjhccsd [1] => ddd [2] => df [3] => dfd [4] => sjhccsd [5] => ddd [6] => df [7] => dfd )`

Comment: Thanks.... its working with print_r($dataArray) but how to print these different variable in different places... im getting difficulty by doing so

Comment: what you mean by  **print these different variable in different places** add some code to your question.

Comment: <?php echo $post['name']; ?> i want to do this but it doesn't work... print_r($post['name']); print_r print the name as well but also it gives error "undefined index name"

Comment: <?php foreach($users as $post):?>
               <?php
                  $class = $post->name;.... in view it says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: echo $post['name'];--------- this code in view post the name correctly but also gives this error---------------A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name

Filename: public/dashboard.php

Line Number: 59-------------------------